# Extracting list data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I am using jQuery. How do I extract list data effectively?

My list has:

```
<li class="add"><a href="#">Data1</a></li>
<li class="add"><a href="#">Data2</a> </li>
 ...
```

My jQuery has:

```
$(".add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Here is to get the value of Data1 and Data2...
    // How do I alert Data1, Data2 effectively?
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

or just

```
  $('li.add a').each(function() {
    data.push($(this).text());
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$('.add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Initialize an array for all texts
  var data = [];

  // For each <li> with class 'add'...
  $('li.add').each(function() {
    // ...append the element's text to the data array
    data.push($(this).text());
  });

  // Just for testing: Alert the array as a string
  alert(data.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
$('.add').click( function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 data = [];
 //loop over each li:
 $('li.add').each( function() {
  //Get the a and the text contents of that
  data.push($(this).find('a').text());
 }
 alert(data.join(','));
}
```

This is a slight variation on Ferdinand's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any comfort, I did something like this recently for a project. I wanted to have it to where you could search the information and highlight text in the page. But I wanted to do it against the data itself (meaning not to hit the HTML each time).

http://www.ffin.com/onlinebankingfaq

If you look at the JavaScript code, you can see how I set up the data, which may help you.